# number_with_precision For Prices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am aware of [`number_to_currency`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_currency), but wanted to use `number_with_precision` to output a price for some products in a db

I have a `prices` stored in a db, which has column type `decimal precision: 10, scale: 2`. The prices are stored as `3.00` and `2.99`

I have a problem outputting the prices - it outputs correctly for the `2.99` price, but only outputs `3.0` for the other

Do you have any information on how to get all numbers to show two decimal places regardless of their value?

Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
#app/models/feature.rb
def price=(price)
    number_with_precision price
end
```

Comment: Updated question - I think it's a problem with my setter

Comment: Why have I been downvoted?

Comment: So your question says "output a price..." and you are showing us a setter.  Can you explain what you are trying to do?  Why do have that setter?

Comment: I have the setter to set the price. So if the price is outputted, it's automatically set as a price - I don't understand why that would warrent a downvote

Comment: I just happened to ask the question after you asked your question on downvote!  Are you possibly looking for a getter instead of a setter, so that you can format the output to your preference?

Comment: Yes! Sorry - I got angry about someone downvoting what I deem is a valid question. Perhaps a getter would be the right one

Comment: lol okay thank you - I will reword my question for you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specify the number of digits after decimal in the `precision` option:

```
<%= number_with_precision(price, precision: 2) %>
```

`number_with_precision` is from [`ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) module.  To use it where you don't have this helper available, you need to include this module:

```
class MyClass
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def price_to_number(price)
    number_with_precision(price, precision: 2)
  end
end
```

Comment: @coreyward, I didn't really imagine one could read it the way you explained.  Apologies for the confusion, my intention was not to introduce a model for formatting numbers, my intention was to show the usage of this helper method, given the `NumberHelper` is not available in a model or some other part of code.

Answer (score 4):

There's really not a need for a more complicated method to do this in your case. Just use Ruby:

```
'%.2f' % price
# e.g:
'%.2f' % 3 #=> "3.00"
```

Comment: perfectly good way of showing a number with 2 decimal places.

Answer (score -1):

The answer was thus:

```
#app/models/feature.rb
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

  def price
     number_with_precision read_attribute(:price), precision: 2
  end
end
```

Comment: New people attention! Never do this! Don't include ActionView stuff in your model!

`def price=(value)
    p = '%.2f' % value
    write_attribute(:price, p)
end`